# Oracle RAW id columns and JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to develop a simple Java servlet that calls an Oracle 11g XE database.  The database I was provided uses RAW column types for the IDs on all tables.

Initially I tried to just get the data back from JDBC and base64 encode the VARBINARY byte arrays that were being returned so I could pass the results via JSON to the front end system.  However, after base64 decoding and trying to set the byte array back to the column, Oracle/JDBC was not returning data.

I decided to try and have Oracle do the encoding/decoding and was able to get the following queries to fire in Oracle using SQL Developer 2.

```
SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(IDCOLUMN), FIRST_NAME FROM TABLENAME
SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(IDCOLUMN), FIRST_NAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE IDCOLUMN = utl_encode.base64_decode('BASE64STRING')
```

However when executing these queires using JDBC:

```
conn = isConnSupplied ? userConn : ResourceManager.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 try {
   ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(IDCOLUMN), FIRST_NAME FROM TABLENAME");
   try {
     while (rset.next())
       System.out.println (rset.getString(1));   // Print col 1
   } 
   finally {
      try { rset.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
   }
 } 
 finally {
   try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29261: bad argument
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_ENCODE", line 8
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_ENCODE", line 243

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:866)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1491)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
com.pearson.familyportal.servlet.WebController.doPost(WebController.java:97)
com.pearson.familyportal.servlet.WebController.doGet(WebController.java:171)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Question:  What is the best way to deal with the RAW ID column byte arrays when I have to pass these around on the client side?  If letting Oracle do the conversion, what am I doing wrong that JDBC isn't liking?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using RAWTOHEX and HEXTORAW.

Comment: Yep, that worked great.  I used RAWTOHEX and HEXTORAW in prepared statements without issue. SELECT RAWTOHEX(IDCOLUMN), FIRST_NAME FROM TABLENAME SELECT RAWTOHEX(IDCOLUMN), FIRST_NAME FROM TABLENAME WHERE IDCOLUMN = HEXTORAW('HEXSTRING')

Answer (score 0):

I have Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 and Java 1.6,
this code work good

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT utl_encode.base64_encode(ID), NAME FROM raw_table");
        while (rset.next())
        {
            Object obj = rset.getString(1);
            logger.debug(obj);
        }
```

Also i want to say, that Tom Kyte do not recommended use RAW Type.

Comment: I agree the RAW id's don't seem like a good idea, the database is from another system we have to integrate with though, but it is good to know I wasn't crazy on that thought.

Comment: You can try to use different jdbc drivers. I use ojdbc14.jar, perhaps it will work good with Oracle XE. Or may be another one.