# How to map a Oracle table with RAW datatype in a column to a Java JDBC code?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement

How to map a Oracle table with RAW datatype in a column to a Java JDBC code ?

I tried as below but the value get altered when it reach the DB.

```
callableStatement.setBytes("i_signature", signature.getBytes());
```

The value stored in the DB looks like `581F0A15DBB6C27F003F6F26C6A319A5`

This same value is gets converted in the above java code into `3538314630413135444242364332374630303346364632364336413331394135` but the DB expects `581F0A15DBB6C27F003F6F26C6A319A5`.

Comment: What about `.setObject("i_signature", signature);` ?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079398/oracle-raw-id-columns-and-jdbc

Comment: @RC Thanks callableStatement.setString("i_signature", signature); solved the issue.