# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number for RAW(16)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to insert RAW Data from Java JDBC to Oracle but getting exception.

```
String getGUISQL = "SELECT SYS_GUID() FROM DUAL ";
```

this gives `guid` value as return string ***32781B10FF194796ABEFEA39DB398EBE***, Now I try to insert to Oracle DB from Java as below based on guid value received

```
preparedStatment.setString(1, guid));  /// ID RAW(16) Oracle Data Type
```

but exception comes as `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01465: invalid hex number`

Please give me suggestion to correct my error in code.

Comment: Obviously there is a data mismatch. There are functions - RAWTOHEX and HEXTORAW to convert values. Try these as per your need. Refer question , [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079398/oracle-raw-id-columns-and-jdbc)

Comment: It would help if you'd edit your question and show the DDL for the table you're trying to insert data into, along with the Java code you're using. You might also try changing the datatype to `RAW(32)`. See the example given in the [SYS_GUID documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions175.htm). Best of luck.